# Updating viewcontroller after loading .Xib file

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a .Xib file which have a custom view in Xamarin.ios.
This Xib file ,I have added in a viewcontroller.
Now as per the flow first methods of viewcontroller class first loads,
then it loads Xib file.

I have certain functionalities due to which I need to update a method in viewcontroller class,after the .xib file loads.

Lets say I want to change the decrease the width of custom view in viewcontroller class,after the .xib file loaded.

It may be simple,I am new to ios ,So need help

Comment: Let's see if I understood correctly: You want to change the `width` of a custom view which also has a XIB file. This custom view is a child view in a `UIViewController`. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes,I have a controller which have a .xib file (custom view).Now what I need to do if I want to change the width of this customview in controller after the .xib file loaded.I know I can do this by declaring constraint in controller file.But I want to do this after complete .xib file is loaded

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a constraint for the width of the custom view. Take a outlet of the constraint and change its constant when required and call layout if needed to reload the view.

```
 _width.Constraint.Constant = 100;
 View.LayoutIfNeeded (); // The view could be custom view or view controller's view.
```

Comment: Like I said in my comments,I can do this by declaring a constraint.But I have certain functionalities due to which I have to call a viewcontroller method to decrease width after the .xib file is loaded....In short want to refresh the data in viewcontroller after the .xib file loaded

Comment: In which life cycle activity are you loading the xib file ? What exactly do you mean refreshing the data ? Is it refreshing values in a table view or something similar ?

Comment: I am loading this in ViewDidLoad().Refreshing data means changing the width of customview(.Xib file in controller).Problem is-When a cutomview is in viewcontroller class -there is a method getData() is called ,depending on the data is null or not i am setting the width of this customview using constraint,the same getdata is also called in .xib file

Comment: ,now as controller methods executed first -if in getdata data is coming null,then the width of view will be 0,but when the same getdata is called in .xib file data is not null,so in this case i want to send some data to controller so width will be again back to normal

Comment: You can try adding a public method in your custom view to return a bool which specifies if the data is null or not  public bool IsDataExist(){if(getData() == null) return false; else return true;}  Next in view controllers view did appear call IsDataExist() and set the width of the custom view and call layout if needed method to update the view constraints

Comment: So you are saying create a instance of customview class in viewcontroller

Comment: You can get the outlet of the custom view and use that as an instance of customview . Or if in case you are adding it programatically in viewdidLoad you can save it as a global instance .